# Particular Solution of $y''+4y=\sin^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm trying to solve this equation for a general solution, and I have got the homogeneous solution $y_h = c_1\cos(2x)+c_2\sin(2x)$.

When solving the particular solution, I am trying Variation of Parameters, which gives me $y_p = -\cos(2x)\int\frac{\sin(2x)\sin^2(x)}{W}+\sin(2x)\int\frac{\cos(2x)\sin^2(x)}{W}$ and $W$ is the Wronskian. However, I can't really think of an easy way to crack down the second term.

Is there a specific technique here or is there a more convenient approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $2\sin^2x=1-\cos(2x)$ and then use the double angle formula for the cosine once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''+4y=\sin^2(x)$$
$$y''+4y=1-\cos^2(x)=\dfrac 12(1-\cos(2x))$$
Substitute $z=\dfrac 14-2y$
$$z''+4z= \cos(2x)$$
Apply variation of parameters method. Although method of undetermined coefficents is better here.The guess should be:
$$z_p=Ax \sin (2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we can use the general differential operator
$$
y''+4y=1-\cos^2(x)=\frac12\Bigl(1-\cos(2x)\Bigr)\implies\,(D^2+4)y_p=\frac12-\frac14(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})
$$
Then
\begin{align}
y_p&=\frac12(D^2+4)^{-1}\times1-\frac14(D^2+4)^{-1}(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})\\
&=\frac12\Bigl(\frac14+o(D)\Bigr)\times1-\frac14\left[e^{2ix}\frac{1}{(D+2i)^2+4}\times1-e^{-2ix}\frac{1}{(D-2i)^2+4}\times1
\right]\\
&=\frac18-\frac14\left[e^{2ix}\left(-\frac{i}{4D}+\frac{1}{16}+o(D)\right)\times1+e^{-2ix}\left(\frac{i}{4D}+\frac{1}{16}+o(D)\right)\times1\right]\\
&=\frac18-\frac14\left[e^{2ix}\left(-\frac{ix}{4}+\frac{1}{16}\right)+e^{-2ix}\left(\frac{ix}{4}+\frac{1}{16}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac18\Bigl(1-x\sin(2x)-\frac14\cos(2x)\Bigr)
\end{align}

Note that the power series expansion has been used for the operator expression. For instance
$$
(D^2+4)^{-1}=\frac14\left(1-\left(\frac{D}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{D}{2}\right)^4+\ldots\right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{(D+ 2i)^2 +4}=-\frac{i}{4D}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{iD}{64}+\ldots
$$